# Installing Fedora over Fedora without losing disk content. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a problematic Fedora partition and I would like to reinstall Fedora over it again, but I don't want to lose anything I have on the disk.

Is it possible?

If it is not possible, there's any way to access the disk partition to save the contents of /home ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll be on the good way if you have an /home partition: if it so, you will have no problem. Just install without formatting the /home partition. If not, you could copy inside an external hard drive or using an online hosting service the content of your /home, then install your fedora and copy back the content of the /home.

I'll be around to hear from you and the other SuperUsers as well...

Regards

Comment: tar cvpf /some/external/disk/home.tar /home
tar xvpf /some/external/disk/home.tar -C /

Comment: I don't have a /home partition. /home is in the same partition as fedora itself. The problem as I said, is that my current installation of Fedora gives a blank screen after boot, so I do not have access to the main disk, so I cannot tar what is inside.

If I disconnect this hard disk and connect it to an ubuntu machine, will that machine saw the disk? (yes, I am sure the disk is OK, just the boot is broken)

Comment: I would use a liveCD in order to tar the /home (actually I would just copy it, without compression): how it sounds?